# blender crashing when painting texture

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm trying to paint a texture and blender keeps crashing.
Some of the answers to other people with the same ploblem have been: "The scene you are trying to render is too complex for your PC to handle", but my scene is empty, there is only a simple face model with less than 10000 faces and have a good PC, I play games that can render miles of scenery with a bunch of characters and objects on screen, but for some reason I can't make a simple brushstroke of color in the texture of a small model without having to wait a full minute for the brushstroke to load.

Can anyone explain to me if this is normal or if I'm doing something wrong here?

Here is the model:
[image]

Here is Blender crashing:
[image]

Here is Blender's configuration:
[image]

Here is the stats of the CPU when it crashes:
[image]

Comment: You could try zooming in to the mesh so the texture editor has to do less work. I found that painting with the whole mesh visible would sometimes cause freezing.

Answer (score 1):

According to my and others experience after using a boolean modifier texture paint can cause Blender to crash. The workaround that I figured out was to export the object to STL and import it back to Blender. The imported object can be texture painted without problems. Another possibility is to use the remesh modifier within Blender and afterwards the remeshed object can be texture painted as well. I prefer the first method as the mesh remains more similar to the original one, so masking is easier.

Comment: Remesh worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Blender is possibly crashing due to errors. To debug potential crashes, check the debug logs. Follow the steps stated in the link to produce and view such logs.

https://github.com/AC-Panda/b3d-debug/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, I turned off [Normal Falloff](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/brush/falloff.html#front-face-falloff). On my simple models, Blender crashed almost every time, but when I turned it off, it no longer did.